# Read data to matlab with for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to read the data of a file with size about 60 MB into matlab in some variables, but I get errors. This is my code:

```
    clear all ;
    clc ;
    % Reading Input File
    Dataz = importdata('leak0.lis');
    %Dataz = load('leak0.lis');

    for k = 1:1370
foundPosition = 1 ;
for i=1:size(Dataz,1)
    strp = sprintf('I%dz=',k);
    fprintf(strp);
    findValue = strfind(Dataz{i}, strp) ;
    if ~isempty(findValue)
        eval_param = strp + '(foundPosition) = sscanf(Dataz{i},''%*c%*c%*f%*c%*c%f'') ;';
        disp(eval_param);
        % str(foundPosition) = sscanf(Dataz{i},'%*c%*c%*f%*c%*c%f') ;
        eval(eval_param);
        foundPosition = foundPosition + 1 ;
    end
end
end
```

When I debugged it, I found out that the dataz is empty & so it doesn't proceed to next lines. I replace it with fopen, load & etc, but it didn't work.

Comment: Waht is the format of the content of the file?

Comment: this is a snippet of the file:   *** monte carlo  index =            1 ***

 i1z= -17.3439n
 i2z= -24.7754p

Comment: Without for loop on K I got data in matlab work space. I mean if I do for each of k, but the problem is that when I write 1370 time of the following code, the matlab program go to busy state for hours & doesn't answer: foundPosition = 1 ;
for i=1:size(Data,1)
    findValue = strfind(Data{i}, 'i11p=') ;
    if ~isempty(findValue)
        i11p(foundPosition) = sscanf(Data{i},'%*c%*c%*f%*c%*c%f') ;
        foundPosition = foundPosition + 1 ;
    end
end

Comment: so the import data works for this, but when the data is huge, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[From the Matlab help files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), import data is likely failing because it doesn't understand your file format.
From the help files

> Name and extension of the file to import, specified as a string. If importdata recognizes the file extension, it calls the MATLAB helper function designed to import the associated file format (such as load for MAT-files or xlsread for spreadsheets). Otherwise, importdata interprets the file as a delimited ASCII file.
>
> For ASCII files and spreadsheets, importdata expects to find numeric
>   data in a rectangular form (that is, like a matrix). Text headers can
>   appear above or to the left of the numeric data, as follows:

Assuming that your .lis files actually have delimited text.
You should adjust the delimiter in the *importdata* call so that Matlab can understand your file.

```
filename = 'myfile01.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```